# replace function not found in Google Spreadsheets using App Scripts

Tags: string, google-apps-script, replace

I have been searching for a way to replace text inside a string with another text. I searched at SO as well and found link to use .replace and .toString() functions (java ones) but they are NOT being recognized by Google Apps Script Editor.

`s=s.toString().replace(A, b);`

`TypeError: Cannot call method "replace" of undefined. (line 15, file "Code")`

Is there a way hot to do the required?

Thank you

Comment: Try this in the console of your browser.
`"My Country".replace('My','Your');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace returns a string. It doesn't change in place.

```
function stringystuff() {
  var s1="This is my country";
  var s2="your";
  var s3="my";
  s1=s1.replace(s3,s2);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(s1);
}
```

From: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

The replace() method **returns a new string** with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match. If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't say there isn't a `replace` function; but that it cannot call replace method of `undefined`. It means `s` is `undefined` and not a `string` at the line where `replace` is called. You should be figuring out why `s`'s value  changes to  `undefined` in the previous 14 lines.

Also if `A` and `b` are not variables, they should be quoted: `("A","b")`